# Filter Rows by Column Heading

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

Totally new to Angular. I need to build a table that shows news. Each news item has a category, heading, subhead, intro. I need one col for each category:

US       International
Head1    Head1
Sub1     Sub1
Intro1   Intro1
Head2    Head2
Sub2     Sub2
Intro2   Intro2

There will always be the same no of items in each category

So I'm getting a unique list of categories to create the TH's, then for each news item in each category, I want to display a tbody with 3 rows (head, subhead, intro)

Here's my Controller JS

```
window.myApp = this.angular.module('myApp', []);


function NewsController($scope) {
    $scope.newsItems = [
      { category: 'US', headline: 'US Headline 1', subhead: 'US Subhead 1', intro: 'US Intro 1' },
      { category: 'US', headline: 'US Headline 2', subhead: 'US Subhead 2', intro: 'US Intro 2' },
      { category: 'International', headline: 'International Headline 1', subhead: 'International Subhead 1', intro: 'International Intro 1' },
      { category: 'International', headline: 'International Headline 2', subhead: 'International Subhead 2', intro: 'International Intro 2' }
    ];

    // distinct list of categories
    $scope.categories = $scope.newsItems.reduce(function (sum, item) {
        return (sum.indexOf(item.category) == -1 ? sum.concat(item.category) : sum);
    }, []);
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div ng-app>
<table class="news" ng-controller="NewsController">
    <thead>
        <tr class="section hidden-xs text-danger">
            <!-- Distinct List -->
            <th ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{category}}">{{ category }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in newsItems">
        <tr>
            <td class="">{{ item.headline }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">{{ item.subhead }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.intro }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mark2457/WMzYX/2/

I started thinking, I'd get the first from each in row1, second from each for row2, but realized I don't know how to do that. This is just dummy data. Eventually it will probably come from two RSS feeds. I could put each category in it's own controller, but that seems a lot duplication.

(one other point, I need to conditionally add classes to the th and td elements (for example, the second th and td need an additional class that denotes then has hide-able for a responsive layout)

I'd ideally like whole thing to be in a separate file that I can somehow insert into the main HTML if possible

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: You're using a table now to display two lists, or many lists in the future, which could even vary in length. Tables make it really hard in AngularJS to use `ng-repeat` to display this data, can you ditch the tables for say, divs? That would make the answer much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can drop using html `table`, the reason being is that you're actually trying to display multiple lists of data, which you're grouping by a property. Using `table` makes it really hard to do what you're asking, because from the `tr` you can't know which category you should display, as the `tr` isn't a child element of the heading, you can't use two `ng-repeat`s inside of eachother.

```js
angular.module('news', []);

angular.module('news').controller('NewsController', function($scope) {

    $scope.newsItems = [
      { category: 'US', headline: 'US Headline 1', subhead: 'US Subhead 1', intro: 'US Intro 1' },
      { category: 'US', headline: 'US Headline 2', subhead: 'US Subhead 2', intro: 'US Intro 2' },
      { category: 'International', headline: 'International Headline 1', subhead: 'International Subhead 1', intro: 'International Intro 1' },
      { category: 'International', headline: 'International Headline 2', subhead: 'International Subhead 2', intro: 'International Intro 2' }
    ];

    $scope.newsItemsGrouped = {};
    $scope.newsItems.forEach(function(item){
        $scope.newsItemsGrouped[item.category] = $scope.newsItemsGrouped[item.category] || [];
        $scope.newsItemsGrouped[item.category].push(item);
    });

});
```

```css
.category-list {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="news" ng-controller="NewsController">
    <div ng-repeat="(category, items) in newsItemsGrouped" class="category-list">
      <h2>{{ category }}</h2>
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <p>{{ item.headline }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.subhead }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.intro }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Most noteably we're now using two `ng-repeat`s inside of eachother, and the `newsItemsGrouped` is a map of a categories to the list of items part of that category. This way you can read out the category, and the list, now that we have the list per category we can `ng-repeat` on it again, and display every item's properties.

The way you can do the grouping is with plain JavaScript, and with some CSS, you'll have about the layout as you provided in the example.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can;t actually drop the tables because I need to keep the headlines aligned, so if US story 1 is 5 lines and Int story 1 is 6 lines, I need to start story 2 on line 7 for both. I don't know a way to do that without a table (or adding empty lines). It did give me some ideas and I modified my controller to return a combined list so that US1 and Int1 were in same record, then I could use regular ng-repeat. Thanks again. Mark